# How to make a layout fit for any Desktop screen? Website HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

This is my design:

```
<style>
body {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0, .5), rgba(0,0,0,.5)), url('https://www.gamewallpapers.com/wallpapers_slechte_compressie/wallpaper_rune
scape_02_1920x1080.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover; 
  margin: 0;
}
/* IE 6 */
* html #footer {
   position:absolute;
   top:expression((0-(footer.offsetHeight)+
(document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : 
document.body.clientHeight)+(ignoreMe = document.documentElement.scrollTop ?             
document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop))+'px');
}

.nav {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}
.footer {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  position:fixed;
  left:0px;
  bottom:0px;
  height:5%;
  width:100%;
}
.side-bar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  height: 85%;
  background: #000;
  margin-bottom: 2%; margin-top: 4.7%;
}
</style>

<html>
<head>
<title>RuneStake</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="nav">
</div>

<div class="side-bar">
</div>



<div class="footer">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This design works on my browser but it starts going out of proportion on other desktops/browsers. How do I fix this so all the lengths work with all desktops/browsers?

It currently appears like this : www.runestake.x10.bz/home.php

Thanks

Comment: You should take a look at frameworks like bootstrap, they will make your life easier. http://getbootstrap.com

Comment: Don't make margins be a percentage value. Widths and heights are fine as percentages, but margin is something that needs to stay the same for most sites. Your nav height is 10% and the margin-top of the sidebar is 4.7%, so the sidebar is going to overlap the nav.

Comment: But without using percentages, my elements on bigger Desktops i.e iMac's look like there really small. By using percentages I get a more proportioned element but they start moving out of space...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `top: 10%` instead of `margin-top: 4.7%`. If you use margin as a percentage, it will be calculated from the height of the element itself, not its parent (`margin-top: 4.7%` would be 4.7% of 85% of the body height, where `top: 10%` would be 10% of the body height).

```
.side-bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 85%;
  background: #000;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, very well described and I understand now :)